# Example of Periodic groups which are not locally finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that the Tarski Monster groups in one of the example of periodic group which are not locally finite. Are there any other groups which are periodic but not locally finite?

Comment: Do you count the groups where all proper subgroups have order dividing some fixed number as Tarski Monsters, or only the ones where that number is a prime?

Comment: This problem is discussed here: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Burnside_problem#Comments

Comment: Original defination of Tarski Monster group is when it is a prime. But now people have used it also for groups where all proper subgroups have order dividing some fixed number.